# Detecting Browser Window Position with CSS

Tags: css

Is it possible to apply a CSS(3) effect when the browser has scrolled? I have a sticky header / footer and wanted to apply a drop shadow only if the window is not at the top. I know this can be done with JS but wanted to see if it was possible through CSS alone. Thanks.

Comment: I don't believe it is :( Thought maybe some viewport manipulation could pay off, but no luck. I'm assuming you're after an effect like on http://techcrunch.com/ (top menu)?

Comment: @o.v. Something similar. I think my workaround will probably be adding and removing a class on scroll with JS then using the CSS(3) effects on the class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added in JS to add a class to the header on scroll. Couldn't find a way to do it strictly with CSS.